# struct.unpack error only at last iteration of the while loop

Tags: python, struct, fft

I want to make a real time fft analysis of my audio file, when converting from binary of the wav file to int with struct.unpack I get the error:

```
 data_int =struct.unpack(format, data)
struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 4096 bytes
```

Every time I change the audio format or rate to match the 4096 buffersize goes up 2x or something similar.

What is weird is that in the while loop, I see no error only at the last iteration of the while loop, and then I can't get out of it.

```
import numpy as np
import pyaudio
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import wave
import argparse
from struct import *
import struct

#Get file
filename = 'snare16.wav'  

# Set chunk size of 1024 samples per data frame
chunk = 1024

# Open the sound file
wf = wave.open(filename, 'rb')

# Create an interface to PortAudio
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

# Open a .Stream object to write the WAV file to
stream = p.open(format = p.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth()),
                channels = wf.getnchannels(),
                rate = wf.getframerate(),
                output = True)

# Read data in chunks
data = wf.readframes(chunk)

#Convert binary numbers into int (Bit-Depth)
count = len(data)/2
format = "%dh"%(count) #results in '2048h' as format: 2048 short

# Play the sound by writing the audio data to the stream
while data != '':
#play audio
    stream.write(data)

#Read the chunk each rate
    data = wf.readframes(chunk)

#Convert data into np array, i.e integers
    data_int =struct.unpack(format, data)
```

Comment: Suppose you have a file with 10 bytes and you read it with a chunk size of 4 bytes. How many bytes to you get in each iteration?

Comment: Hmm I maybe have an idea how this could be happening. You get 4bytes, 4 bytes, 2bytes, right? So I could use chunk size / 2 to read the file?

Comment: Ok, suppose you have a file with 15 bytes and you read it in chunks of 4 bytes. What would you get in this case? Would using half the chunk size help you?

Comment: I fixed it  by putting the formatting of the data inside the loop so it constantly calculates the size, thank you!